# Is somehow possible to duplicate a form with js/dojo/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

lets'say i have a form, with like this :

```
<form name="frmMail" method="POST" action="save.do" dojoType="dijit.form.Form" onSubmit="return this.validate();">
    <label for="mailSubject">subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="mailSubject"
            dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
            required="true"
            value="" />
    <label for="mailContent">Content</label>        
    <textarea name="mailContent"
            dojoType="dijit.Editor"
            propercase="true" ></textarea>

    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" id="save" name="save" >Save</button>
</form>
```

is it possible to duplicate this code with javascript? Right now, i am putting all this in div, and i copy the innerHtml data, but its not good, cause the id of each elements are duplicated.
any thoughts?

UPDATE

```
<form name="frmMail" dojoattachevent="onreset:_onReset,onsubmit:_onSubmit" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" action="save.do" method="POST" id="dijit_form_Form_0" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Form_0">
<label for="mailSubject">subject</label>
<div wairole="presentation" id="widget_dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_0" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitValidationTextBox dijitTextBoxError dijitValidationTextBoxError dijitError dijitTextBoxFocused dijitValidationTextBoxFocused dijitTextBoxErrorFocused dijitValidationTextBoxErrorFocused dijitErrorFocused dijitFocused" role="presentation" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_0"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input type="text" wairole="presentation" readonly="" tabindex="-1" value="? " class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input type="text" name="mailSubject" autocomplete="off" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" aria-invalid="true" id="dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_0" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" value=""></div></div>
<label for="mailContent">Content</label>        
<div widgetid="dijit_Editor_0" class=" dijitEditor"><div>
<div lang="" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" tabindex="0" wairole="toolbar" class="dijit dijitToolbar" role="toolbar" id="dijit_Toolbar_0" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_Toolbar_0"><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonDisabled dijitDisabled" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_5"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_5_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_5_label" id="dijit_form_Button_5" title="Undo" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="true"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconUndo"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_5_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Undo</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value="" disabled=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonDisabled dijitDisabled" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_6"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_6_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_6_label" id="dijit_form_Button_6" title="Redo" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="true"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconRedo"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_6_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Redo</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value="" disabled=""></span><div wairole="presentation" class="dijitToolbarSeparator dijitInline" role="presentation" id="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_0" widgetid="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_0" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonDisabled dijitDisabled" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_7"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_7_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_7_label" id="dijit_form_Button_7" title="Cut" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="true"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_7_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Cut</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value="" disabled=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonDisabled dijitDisabled" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_8"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_8_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_8_label" id="dijit_form_Button_8" title="Copy" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="true"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_8_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Copy</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value="" disabled=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_9"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_9_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_9_label" id="dijit_form_Button_9" tabindex="-1" title="Paste" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_9_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Paste</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><div wairole="presentation" class="dijitToolbarSeparator dijitInline" role="presentation" id="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_1" widgetid="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_1" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitToggleButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_ToggleButton_0"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_ToggleButton_0_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_ToggleButton_0_label" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_0" tabindex="-1" title="Bold" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconBold"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_0_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Bold</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitToggleButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_ToggleButton_1"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_ToggleButton_1_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_ToggleButton_1_label" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_1" tabindex="-1" title="Italic" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconItalic"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_1_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Italic</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitToggleButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_ToggleButton_2"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_ToggleButton_2_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_ToggleButton_2_label" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_2" tabindex="-1" title="Underline" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconUnderline"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_2_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Underline</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitToggleButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_ToggleButton_3"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_ToggleButton_3_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_ToggleButton_3_label" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_3" tabindex="-1" title="Strikethrough" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconStrikethrough"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_ToggleButton_3_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Strikethrough</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><div wairole="presentation" class="dijitToolbarSeparator dijitInline" role="presentation" id="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_2" widgetid="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_2" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_10"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_10_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_10_label" id="dijit_form_Button_10" tabindex="-1" title="Numbered List" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconInsertOrderedList"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_10_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Numbered List</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_11"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_11_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_11_label" id="dijit_form_Button_11" tabindex="-1" title="Bullet List" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconInsertUnorderedList"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_11_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Bullet List</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_12"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_12_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_12_label" id="dijit_form_Button_12" tabindex="-1" title="Indent" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconIndent"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_12_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Indent</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonDisabled dijitDisabled" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_13"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_13_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_13_label" id="dijit_form_Button_13" title="Outdent" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="true"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconOutdent"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_13_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Outdent</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value="" disabled=""></span><div wairole="presentation" class="dijitToolbarSeparator dijitInline" role="presentation" id="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_3" widgetid="dijit_ToolbarSeparator_3" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_14"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_14_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_14_label" id="dijit_form_Button_14" tabindex="-1" title="Align Left" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconJustifyLeft"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_14_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Align Left</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_15"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_15_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_15_label" id="dijit_form_Button_15" tabindex="-1" title="Align Right" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconJustifyRight"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_15_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Align Right</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_16"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_16_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_16_label" id="dijit_form_Button_16" tabindex="-1" title="Align Center" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconJustifyCenter"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_16_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Align Center</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span><span lang="" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_17"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-dijit_form_Button_17_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_17_label" id="dijit_form_Button_17" tabindex="-1" title="Justify" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconJustifyFull"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="dijit_form_Button_17_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText dijitDisplayNone">Justify</span></span></span><input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value=""></span></div></div><div class="dijitEditorIFrameContainer"><iframe frameborder="0" id="dijit_Editor_0_iframe" style="border: medium none; width: 100%; height: 300px;" src="javascript:parent.dijit.byId(&quot;dijit_Editor_0&quot;)._iframeSrc" class="dijitEditorIFrame"></iframe></div><div></div></div><textarea propercase="true" dojotype="dijit.Editor" name="mailContent" id="dijit_Editor_0" dir="ltr" class="dijitEditor" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: -1000px;"></textarea>

<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="save"><span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"><span waistate="labelledby-save_label" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="button" aria-labelledby="save_label" id="save" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span><span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="save_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText">Save</span></span></span><input type="submit" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" class="dijitOffScreen" value="" name="save"></span>
```

Comment: Only the button has an ID as far as I see. Why don't you just change the id? Or what do you want to achieve eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can dynamically change the `id` of elements in a selection quite easily:

```
var newForm = $('form')
                       .clone()
                       .find('[id]') // find elements with an id set
                           .attr('id', function(idx, oldId) { // dynamically set each of these elements
                               return 'new_' + oldId; // to new_ + the old id value
                           })
                       .end(); // return to the form selection
```

I'm not familiar enough with Dojo to know whether something similar could be achieved, but I expect it could.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to edit my answer, since it has already been accepted and since I am less than 100% sure that this is correct, since I am not familiar with Dojo. However, this code appears to be something close to a port of my other answer to Dojo:

```
var oldform = dojo.query('form'),
    newform = dojo.clone(oldform);

newform.query('[id]').forEach(function(el){
    el.id = 'new_' + el.id;
});
```

Comment: the ideas of your answers may be correct, but its not exactly what i want. Using dojo and adding widget, the clone fonction do exactly the same as innerHtml, i have manually to rename the id. it would have been ok like that, but most important i also have to deal with all the widgetid generated by dojo

Comment: @stunaz It's hard to work your requirements out if you don't make it clear what you need. I can't see dojo IDs on those elements -- can you post your document as the browser has interpreted it? (I.e. copy/paste from Firebug/Chrome console etc.)

Comment: i have pasted the generated code, but as i see, it became too complicated, because i dont exactly how dojo use that code or else how dojos generates other codes. thats why i was looking for an another solution, ie to clone the clean html code without dojo, and then add dojo widget to the cloned code. that must work, but i dont know if i can apply a dojowidget to an existing code, am still googling it

Comment: @stunaz Clone the original before you add the Dojo widget.

Answer (score 1):

Here is right answer for dojo

```
                dojo.query('[id]', newform).forEach(function(e){
                e.id = 'new_' + e.id;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't just clone all the nodes.  Dijit widgets are JS objects associated with the DOM, so simply renaming and copying DOM nodes after the fact won't work.

Instead, clone the code (dojo.clone on a DOM node) before Dojo parses and instantiates the widget.  I think you'll find this much simpler in the end.  To do this, you would have to call dojo.parser.parse() manually on the document and/or fragment(s)  If you had this snippet in a string, you could just insert it in the document twice with innerHTML then call parse()

You'd still have that one id="save" to deal with.  You could assign an id value to that button manually, either with string manipulation or using dojo.query.  Don't forget, you'd probably want to do the same for the form name to make it unique.

Comment: yeah thanks, i have first duplicate the node, than i hadded the dojo features dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example what I mean:

```
var i = 0; //somewhere globally

var formClone = document.frmMail.cloneNode(true);
formClone.save.id = "save" + i;
i++;
document.body.appendChild(formClone); // adding somewhere
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yekvp/1/) (note, I only use jQuery to attach the click handler... was easier ;))

Reference: [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) where it actually says:

> Note that `cloneNode` may lead to duplicate element-ids in a document!

This is just the way it is. It is your responsibility then to change the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery, but you'll have to change the id just as in your raw DOM impl.

```
var form = $('form');
var clonedForm = form.clone();
clonedForm.find('button').attr('id', 'save2');
form.after(clonedForm);
```

You can see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/ydBpR/.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use the parser if we want to convert the dom nodes to widgets.

```
var oldform = dojo.query('form'),
var newform = dojo.clone(oldform);

newform.query('[id]').forEach(function(el){
    el.id = 'new_' + el.id;
});


dojo.body().appendChild(newform);
//force body to be parsed for widgets
dojo.parser.parse(dojo.body());
```